# Problem showing cropped images in tableView

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, crop

I have a customised `UITableView` in which I have a label, 2 buttons and 2 images. One of the images is a cropped image made from the centre of a larger image (which is shown in the same table-view on tapping this cropped image in table-view). Currently, I'm using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to crop the image. So initially, the cropped images are shown in table-view and when the user taps the image, the height of cell increases to show the larger(original) image which replaces the cropped image. When the user taps another cropped image, the previously enlarged image is replaced with its cropped version(and its cell height reduced) and the cropped image currently tapped is enlarged as previously. This process continues... When I load the cropped images initially, it happens perfectly.The problem is, if an image is enlarged-reduced twice/thrice..., the cropped image displayed in table-view is a zoomed in version of the cropped image! It seems that the cropped image is further cropped automatically. I've made an array of cropped images and an array of original images. Inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I've displayed the images using these arrays. My initial guess is that this has something to do with cell reuse, but I could'nt find anything on that. Any ideas how to solve this problem?